# Exclude properties from nested instances using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson provides the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation that can be used to exclude properties from serialization in a class, or in a field owned by that class. Unfortunately, it does not allow nested properties (ie: properties of descendants) to be excluded.

Give the following object heirarchy:

```
static class Innermost {
  public String innerField0 = "c";
  public String innerField1 = "d";
}

static class Nested {
  public Innermost next = new Innermost();
}

static class Top {
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({"next.innerField1"}) // no effect
  public Nested next = new Nested();
}
```

Is there a mechanism that allows `innerField1` to be excluded from the serializations of the `Top` type, without excluding it from serializations of the `Nested` or `Innermost` types?

Ideally, the serializations of `Innermost`, `Nested`, and `Top` would, each respectively, look like the following:

```
{"innerField0":"c","innerField1":"d"}
{"next":{"innerField0":"c","innerField1":"d"}}
{"next":{"next":{"innerField0":"c"}}}
```

I am using Jackson version 2.8.1